# JpaSystemException: could not read a hi value - you need to populate the table:

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-data

i have web-jpa project, my project work from postgres and mysql database, but when I add new data in mysql db i get exception:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not read a hi value - you need to populate the table: hibernate_sequence; nested exception is org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: could not read a hi value - you need to populate the table: hibernate_sequence

ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-5] <unknown>.<unknown> could not read a hi value - you need to populate the table: hibernate_sequence
```

**Stacktrace**

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not read a hi value - you need to populate the table: hibernate_sequence; nested exception is org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: could not read a hi value - you need to populate the table: hibernate_sequence
    ...
root cause

org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not read a hi value - you need to populate the table: hibernate_sequence; nested exception is org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: could not read a hi value - you need to populate the table: hibernate_sequence
    ...
root cause

org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: could not read a hi value - you need to populate the table: hibernate_sequence
    ...
```

This is my entities class:
**User**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS_TABLE")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "USERS_NAME")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "USERS_EMAIL")
    private String email;
}
```

**UserKey**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS_KEY")
public class UserKey {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "KEY_COLUMN")
    private int key;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "USERS_ID")
    private User user;
}
```

Comment: Problem is solved, need add  `insert into mysqldb.hibernate_sequence(next_val) values(0)`

Comment: I will instead recommend `INSERT INTO hibernate_sequence (next_val) VALUES (1);` Inserting 0 seems to result unexpected behavior for me. I don't know why it happens, but  value `0` results in first `repo.save()` triggering twice.